# C++ Морской Бой - многопалубные корабли

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Написал игру морской бой и реализовал все, что требуется кроме одного. Многопалубные корабли. У меня все корабли однопалубные. Как изменить код таким образом, чтобы было с каждой стороны по 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 палубных 5 кораблей?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>

using namespace std;

const int SIZEf = 10;
int field[SIZEf][SIZEf] = {};

HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

char s1[256];

void GotoXY(int X, int Y)
{
    COORD coord = { X, Y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, coord);
}

void menu()
{
    int f = 1, k, code;

    cout << "\n\n"; // * фигура
    for (int x = 0; x < 13; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == y && y < 13 / 2 || x + y == 13 - 1 && y > 13 / 2 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t  ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    } // *

    GotoXY(27, 12);
    cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
    GotoXY(30, 13);
    cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
    cout << "\n\n\t\t«Морской бой» — игра для двух участников, в которой игроки по очереди называют координаты на неизвестной им карте соперника. Если у соперника по этим координатам имеется корабль (координаты заняты), то корабль или его часть «топится», а попавший получает право сделать ещё один ход";
    do
    {
        k = 0;
        code = _getch();
        if (code == 224 || code == 0)
        {
            code = _getch();
        }

        if (code == 80)
        {
            f = f * (-1);
            if (f == 1)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else if (f == 2)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t   --> Выход <--";
            }
        }
        else if (code == 72)
        {
            f = f * (-1);
            if (f == 1)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t--> Новая игра <--";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else if (f == 2)
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t       Выход    ";
            }
            else
            {
                GotoXY(27, 12);
                cout << "\t\t\t    Новая игра    ";
                GotoXY(30, 13);
                cout << "\t\t\t   --> Выход <--";
            }
        }
        else if (code == 13)
        {
            k = 1;
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    }

    while (k == 0);
    {
        if (f != 1)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void figure1()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t ";
            }
            if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
            {
                cout << "      \t\t\t\t\t";
                string h = "Морской Бой!";
                for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                {
                    Sleep(60);
                    cout << h[i];
                }
                break;
            } // **
        }
        cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
    }
    Sleep(1500); // пауза // *
    cout << "\a"; // звук переключения меню
}

void reminder1()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t    Напоминание:\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t    Нажмите крестик сверху, чтобы выйти из игры\n\t\t\t       При этом достижения не сохраняются!";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t";
    string h = "................................."; // ** Искусственное ожидание с помощью имитации загрузки визуализированное точками
    for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
    {
        Sleep(50);
        cout << h[i];
    } // **
    cout << "\n\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
}

void win()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        if (x <= 1)
        {
            system("Color 05");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tП";
            system("Color 15");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " о";
            system("Color 25");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " з";
            system("Color 35");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " д";
            system("Color 48");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " р";
            system("Color 65");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " а";
            system("Color 85");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " в";
            system("Color 93");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " л";
            system("Color A5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " я";
            system("Color B5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " е";
            system("Color C0");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " м";
            system("Color E5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tВ";
            system("Color F5");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " а";
            system("Color 75");
            Sleep(200);
            cout << " с";
            Sleep(200);
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
                {
                    if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
                    {
                        cout << "    \t* ";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "    \t ";
                    }
                    if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
                    {
                        cout << "      \t\t\t\t\t";
                        string h = "Вы выиграли!";
                        for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                        {
                            Sleep(60);
                            cout << h[i];
                        }
                        break;
                    } // **
                }
                cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
            } // *
        }
    }
}

void ad() // Небольшая реклама 1
{
    system("cls");
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++) // * Создали квадрат
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++)
        {
            if (x == 0 || x == 15 - 1 || y == 0 || y == 15 - 1)
            {
                cout << "    \t* ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "    \t ";
            }
            if (x == 6) // ** Опускаемся ниже, чтобы написать текст внутри квадрата
            {
                cout << "      \t\t\t\tНебольшая рекламная интеграция:\n\n      \t\t\t\t             ";
                string h = "Ставки на Рамина! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Большие выигрыши! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Быстрые решения! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t             Надежный президент! Один только Рамин!\n\n      \t\t\t\t               Голосуйте за одного только Рамина\n\n      \t\t\t\t                     Земля ему пухом...\n\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < h.length(); i++)
                {
                    Sleep(40);
                    cout << h[i];
                }
                break;
            } // **
        }
        cout << endl; // эндл чтобы создавать строки для квадрата
    } //
    Sleep(3300);
    system("cls");
}

void tableShow()
{
    system("cls");
    cout << endl << endl << "\t\t\t\t";
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        cout << counter;
        cout << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t==========================================================================";

    counter = 0;

    cout << endl << endl << "\t\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf; i++)
    {
        if (i == 5)
        {
            cout << "\t        ==========================================================================\n\n\n\t\t";
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && j == 0)
            {
                counter++;
                cout << "\t" << counter << " |";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 5)
            {
                cout << "\t" << field[i][j];
            }
            else if (i < 5)
            {
                cout << "\t0";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << field[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl << "\t\t";
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    system("Color 75");

    //menu();
    //figure1();
    //reminder1();

    int x, y;

    int enemyShipCounter = 0; // * Расположение и количество вражеских кораблей
    while (true)
    {
        x = rand() % SIZEf;
        if (x <= 4)
        {
            y = rand() % SIZEf;
            field[x][y] = 1;
            enemyShipCounter++;
            if (enemyShipCounter == 10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } // *


    int myShipCounter = 0; // * Расположение и количество моих кораблей
    while (true)
    {
        x = rand() % SIZEf;
        if (x >= 5)
        {
            y = rand() % SIZEf;
            field[x][y] = 1;
            myShipCounter++;
            if (myShipCounter == 10)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    } // *

    tableShow();

    bool isMyRound = false;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\t\tВведите координаты: ";
        do
        {
            cin >> x;
            cin >> y;
            if (x >= 6 || x <= 0 || y <= 0)
            {
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВведите координаты которые выше 6 строки (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1), чтобы стрелять по вражескому полю!\n\n";
                cout << "\t\t\t\tВведите координаты: ";
            }
        } while (x >= 6 || x <= 0 || y <= 0);
        {
            x--;
            y--;
        }

        if (field[x][y] == 1)
        {
            cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВы попали по вражескому кораблю!\a" << endl;
            field[x][y] = 5;
            Sleep(3300);

            tableShow();

            bool ship_detect = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZEf - 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
                {
                    if (field[i][j] == 1)
                    {
                        ship_detect = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ship_detect == true)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ship_detect == false)
            {
                cout << "\t\tВы выиграли!!! Все корабли соперника потеплены!" << endl;
                Sleep(4000);
                win();
                Sleep(2000);
                ad();
                break;
            }
            isMyRound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\t\t\t\tВы промахнулись!" << endl;
            isMyRound = false;
            Sleep(3400);
            tableShow();
        }

        int BotX, BotY; // * ход бота
        int Direction = -1;
        bool BotHit = false;
        bool BotHitForSecondBotHit = false;
        bool SecondBotHit = false;
        bool BotMiss[4] = { false, false, false, false }; //Попадание бота по четырём сторонам
        while (isMyRound == false)
        {
            cout << "\t\tХод бота...\n\n";
            if (BotHit == true)
            {
                if (SecondBotHit == false)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Direction = 1 + rand() % 4;
                        if (Direction == 1 && BotMiss[0] == false && BotY > 0)
                        {
                            BotY--; //Стреляет левее
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 2 && BotMiss[1] == false && BotX > 5)
                        {
                            BotX--; //Стреляет выше
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 3 && BotMiss[2] == false && BotY < 9)
                        {
                            BotY++; //Стреляет правее
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 4 && BotMiss[3] == false && BotX < 9)
                        {
                            BotX++; //Стреляет ниже
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true; //Если никуда не получилось выстрелить
                        }
                        if (BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true)
                        {
                            break; //Если уже были попытки выстрелить по всем сторонам
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                { //При втором попадании стреляет в направлении, в котором раньше стрелял
                    if (Direction == 1 && BotY > 0)
                    {
                        BotY--;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 2 && BotX > 5)
                    {
                        BotX--;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 3 && BotY < 9)
                    {
                        BotY++;
                    }
                    else if (Direction == 4 && BotX < 9)
                    {
                        BotX++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SecondBotHit = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                BotX = rand() % 4 + 5;
                BotY = rand() % 10;
            }
            int CoutBotX = BotX + 1;
            int CoutBotY = BotY + 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\tБот ввел координаты: x[" << CoutBotX << "] и y[" << CoutBotY << "]\n";

            if (field[BotX][BotY] == 1)
            {
                if (BotHit == true)
                {
                    BotHitForSecondBotHit = true;
                }
                if (BotHitForSecondBotHit == true)
                {
                    SecondBotHit = true;
                }
                BotHit = true;
                cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот попал по нашему кораблю!\a" << endl;
                field[BotX][BotY] = 5;

                Sleep(5500);

                tableShow();

                field[BotX][BotY] = -1;

                bool ship_detect = false;
                for (int i = 6; i < SIZEf; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < SIZEf; j++)
                    {
                        if (field[i][j] == 1)
                        {
                            ship_detect = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (ship_detect == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (ship_detect == false)
                {
                    cout << "\t\t\t\tБот выиграл!!! Все наши корабли потеплены!" << endl;
                    Sleep(5500);
                    ad();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (field[BotX][BotY] != -1)
                {
                    cout << "\n\t\t\t\tБот промахнулся! Ваша очередь..." << endl;
                    isMyRound = true;
                }
                BotHitForSecondBotHit = false;
                if (Direction != -1)
                {
                    BotMiss[Direction - 1] = true;
                    if ((BotMiss[0] == true && BotMiss[1] == true && BotMiss[2] == true && BotMiss[3] == true) || SecondBotHit == true)
                    {
                        BotHit = false;
                        for (int x = 0; x != 4; x++)
                        {
                            BotMiss[x] = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (SecondBotHit == false && BotHit == true)
                    {
                        if (Direction == 1)
                        {
                            BotY++; //Направляет координату правее
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 2)
                        {
                            BotX++; //Направляет координату ниже
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 3)
                        {
                            BotY--; //Направляет координату левее
                        }
                        else if (Direction == 4)
                        {
                            BotX--; //Направляет координату выше
                        }
                    }
                }
                SecondBotHit = false;
                Sleep(5500);
                tableShow();
            }
        } // *
    }

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Нереализованное - многопалубные корабли
```

Answer (score 3):

Первое что приходит в голову- почитай про ООП. Одно из главных качеств хорошего кода, это возможность удобно его редактировать и дополнять. Для этого код нужно хорошо структурировать. Если бы ты определился с абстракциями и реализовал несколько классов (например класс поля, корабля, игрока), то у тебя бы не возникло вопросов "а как добавить".

Касаемо твоего вопроса:
Можно заполнять матрицу числами от 0 до 5. Допустим пять петёрок подряд это 5-ти палубник.
Случайным образом выбираешь точку и направление, при этом сразу проверяшь, не выходит ли последовательность за пределы массива.

Что бы проверить уничтожен ли 5-палубник, обходишь массив- если пятерок нет, значит корабль уничтожен.

Если нужно несколько 2 ух палубных: можно выделить для них несколько чисел с помощью перечисления. Например числа 2, 6,12 14 будут отвечать за 2-палубники:

```
    enum two_ships{TWO1= 2, TWO2 = 6, TWO3 = 12, TWO4 = 14};
```